# open multiple datafile in a list with python

Tags: python-3.x

There is a list of data file :

```py
files = ['robot_execution_failure/lp1.data', 'robot_execution_failure/lp2.data', 'robot_execution_failure/lp3.data', 'robot_execution_failure/lp4.data', 'robot_execution_failure/lp5.data']
```

All the file needs to be opened and then readline

```
for file in files:
    f=open(file)
    lines=f.readlines()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

What exactly is your question? What do you want to do with the lines in the file?

Comment: @PascalBugnion. I was able to open a file with some data in it with this line of code: f = open('robot_execution_failure/lp1.data'), lines = f.readlines(), lines[:5] and give the output as ['normal\n',
 '\t-1\t-1\t63\t-3\t-1\t0\n',
 '\t0\t0\t62\t-3\t-1\t0\n',
 '\t-1\t-1\t61\t-3\t0\t0\n',
 '\t-1\t-1\t63\t-2\t-1\t0\n']. Now I want to open five files and readline to a list just like I did for one file.